# IE6-8 unable to download file from HTTPS site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, https, mime-types

I have an MVC .Net application that has actions that return report files, usually `.xslx`:

```
byte[] data = GetReport();
return File(data, 
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", 
    "filename.xlsx");
```

This works great in testing and in all browsers, but when we put this on an SSL site it fails for IE6, 7 and 8 (all the proper browsers still work fine) with this unhelpful error:

[image: Unable to download filename from server. Unable to open this Internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later.]

This used to work in a legacy application (non-MVC) that this action replaces.

We can't tell our users to change anything locally - about 60% are still on IE6!

How can I fix this using MVC?

### Update

Further digging reveals that this is a fundamental failure in IE6-8. According to [Eric Law's IE internals blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/02/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https-when-no-cache.aspx) this happens because, during an SSL connection, IE treats the no-cache directive as an absolute rule. So, rather than not cache a copy, it considers no-cache to mean that it shouldn't be possible to save a copy to disk even when 
`Content-Disposition:attachment` and with an explicit prompt for a download location.

Obviously this is wrong, but while it's fixed in IE9 we're still stuck with all the IE6-8 users.

Using MVC's action filter attributes produces the following headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma:no-cache
```

Using Fiddler to change these on the fly we can verify the headers that need to be returned instead:

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
```

Note the order of the `Cache-Control` **must** have `no-store` *before* `no-cache` and that the `Pragma` directive **must** be removed entirely.

This is a problem - we use MVC's action attributes extensively and I really don't want to rewrite them from scratch. Even if we could IIS throws an exception if you try to remove the `Pragma` directive.

How do you make Microsoft's MVC and IIS return the no-cache directive that Microsoft's IE6-8 can handle under HTTPS? I do not want to allow private caching of the response (as per this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996353/internet-explorer-error-using-asp-mvc-4-0-fileresult)) or ignore the MVC built in methods with an override (as per my own answer, which is just my current best hack).

Comment: @tpeczek see update - I'm not looking to override MVC's action filters if at all possible, though I'll check that answer out.

Comment: @tpeczek also the answer to that question appears to be to use `Cache-Control:private`, which would then mean that if a user downloads the same file twice in the same session they'll get a copy from their local browser cache rather than the latest data. It's not a fix. I need to tell the browser not to cache (but do allow downloads) in a format that IE can understand

Comment: Let's just be clear about this question - I want to know how to make MVC output the cache directives that IE6-8 understands, **not** that making the cache private can have a similar effect. I have similar symptoms, but [Calin's question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996353/internet-explorer-error-using-asp-mvc-4-0-fileresult) is no use to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've come up with a workaround, but it's a definite hack - this is a new cache attribute to replace the built-in `[OutputCache]` one:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class IENoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection &&
            string.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.Browser, "IE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.MajorVersion < 9)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.ClearHeaders();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        }

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

It's a workaround at best though - what I really want is to extend the existing `[OutputCache]` and `Response.Cache` structures so that they have the desired output suitable for legacy IEs.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar approach in that I had a BaseController class

```
[OutputCache(Duration=0)]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    //snip snip: some utility stuff and shared endpoints among all my controllers
}
```

That caused the above mentioned problems in IE8. Applying the `[IENoCacheAttribute]` as shown above didn't work however. The problem is that the instruction `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.ClearHeaders()` removes all of my headers including eventual `Content-Disposition` headers etc... causing the file download to not happen correctly.

My approach was therefore to overwrite the default `OutputCacheAttribute.cs` in such a way that in case of IE it didn't apply any kind of caching headers, especially the problematic `no-cache` ones.

```
public class EnhancedOutputCacheAttribute : OutputCacheAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

        if (!IsFileResultAndOldIE(filterContext))
            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        else
        {
            //try the best to avoid any kind of caching
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0));
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5D));
        }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!IsFileResultAndOldIE(filterContext))
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!IsFileResultAndOldIE(filterContext))
            base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!IsFileResultAndOldIE(filterContext))
            base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> for FileResults and if the browser is < IE9</returns>
    private bool IsFileResultAndOldIE(dynamic filterContext)
    {
        return filterContext.Result is FileResult &&
               filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection &&
               string.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.Browser, "IE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
               filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.MajorVersion < 9;
    }

}
```

Here's the corresponding gist: https://gist.github.com/4633225

Comment: Very useful (and +1). Unfortunately, what with IE being so slow and only making two requests at a time I need it to cache more than the other browsers.

Comment: I've modified the solution here to also check for FileContentResult:

    bool result = (filterContext.Result is FileResult 
    || filterContext.Result is FileContentResult)

Comment: @stevieg: You don't have to check for FileContentResult explicitly, as it derives from FileResult.